# difference between . operator and [] in EL

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, el

It might seem silly and very naive question but I always get confuse how to use . and [] operator in EL. I am lost in the question 7 "Head first Servlet &JSP". So the confusions i have

1. what is difference between `${foo[bar]}` and `${foo["bar"]}`
2. How come `${foo.bar}` equal to `${foo["bar"]}` and not `${foo[bar]}`
3. How to conclude `${foo["5"]}` is valid for Map and not for Array or list
4. How to conclude `${foo[5]}` is valid for  Array or List and not for Maps.

I read the book but still very confused.
PLease can someone guide me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. what is difference between ${foo[bar]} and ${foo["bar"]}

The difference between the two is that in the former, you are accessing **foo** 
 collection with the **bar** variable, while in the latter, you are trying to retrieve the key **bar** from the map **foo**

> 2. How come ${foo.bar} equal to ${foo["bar"]} and not ${foo[bar]}

Because `${foo.bar}` simply means that **bar** is like an attribute of **foo** thereby it makes much more sense for `${foo.bar}` and `${foo["bar"]}` to be similar. For `${foo[bar]}` this can also be similar to `${foo["bar"]}` depending on the type of `bar`.

> 3. How to conclude ${foo["5"]} is valid for Map and not for Array or list

Because `"5"` is a string and not an integer.

> 4. How to conclude ${foo[5]} is valid for Array or List and not for Maps.

Similar argument to above question, 5 is an integer.

My EL skills are a bit rusty, please do forgive for any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.